# Are there unsigned copies of the German instrument of surrender in existence?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

My question is intended to solicit advice and guidance with regard to several documents that I purchased as part of a lot of historical documents at an auction.  When I started to look through the documents I was surprised to find some World War 2 Documents.

1. Act of Military Surrender   The document I have has the names of the signers typed in but no actual signatures.  The dates are also blank.  The document is the one signed at Rheims.  The unconditional surrender of the German armed forces was signed by Jodl, on behalf of the OKW. Walter Bedell Smith signed on behalf of the Supreme Commander of the Allied Expeditionary Force and General Ivan Susloparov on behalf of the Soviet High Command  French Major-General François Sevez signed as the official witness.
2. German announcement (radio transcript)  that Hitler was dead and that Donitz was now the German leader - document is in English.
3. Document from Donitz to Jodl to meet with Eisenhower, signed and in German

Comment: What is the question? This is not a *discussion* site.

Comment: New to this sorry.  My question is do unsigned copies of the Act of Military Surrender exist

Comment: Question clarifications should be edited into the original post. Comments are ephemeral, and may be deleted at any time.

Comment: @Scotland3014 I edited your question title based on what I feel you're saying here, but the text of the question is still confusing to me. Please revise it to help people be, well, not confused.

Comment: If you look at the [facsimile of the Instrument of Surrender](https://archive.org/details/GermanySurrendersUnconditionallyFacsimilesOfTheDocuments/page/n37/mode/2up) produced by the US National archives, the actual names of the signatories were not typed on the document.  What you have may be a commemorative item, or a document intended to circulate the terms of the surrender to a wider audience after the original had been signed (and the names of the actual signatories were known).

Comment: Not to mention that the pamphlet referenced by sempaiscuba also contains a facsimile of the order from Doenitz to Jodl, in German, signed, see page 8.